Elementary function with only primes as zeroes
Are there any elementary function (using this definition) with only primes as zeroes?
We have multiple options to choose for this question to be mathematically precise.

Whether we allow complex values or only real values.
Whether we allow the domain to be strictly smaller than $\mathbb{Z}$ (e.g. undefined on composite integers) or not.

I would be happy to know the answer for any possible options as long as it makes sense.
Related:

Elementary functions with zeros only at the positive integers

Is there real or complex analytic function whose positive real zeros are the primes?



Hav you looked here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem

There is a polynomial (in many variables) whose positive range is the primes, maybe that construction would help.

Do you want zeros some subset of the primes, or all the primes?

@mathoverflowUser Yes, but that does not give us a closed-form elementary function. That a elementary function may not be entire (due to log, sqrt, etc) makes it hard to use such good theorems.

@GeraldEdgar I want all primes to be zeroes.

Near miss for the base $B$ pseudoprimes is $\sin(\pi x)^2+\sin(\pi (B^x-B)/x)^2$

@joro This is a great example. It tells us that the question is more subtle than it looks like initially.
